# Different height in different split parts + arrow positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, arrows

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart} 

\begin{document}    


\tikzset{every loop/.style={min distance=1mm,in=110,out=70,looseness=2}}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->, thick, remember picture]
    \node (0) at (-2,1) {};

    \node[draw, shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, inner sep=3ex] (A) at (0,0) {
        \begin{tikzpicture}[->, thick]
            \node[draw, shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, inner sep=1ex] (test) {Sound \nodepart{two} 0 \{ \}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \nodepart{two} 0 \{ \}}; %First Error

    \node[draw, shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2] (B) at (4,0) {Camera     \nodepart{two} 5 \{no\_obj\}};

    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
         (A) edge [loop above] node [above] {no\_obj} (A)
         (A.one east) edge node [above] {obj} (B.one west)

         (test.one east) edge node [below] {no\_obj, obj} (B.two west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My question is, how can I get the second node part from the outer node as small as the second node part from the `Sound` or `Camera` node?

I realy dont know why this happens and I hope you can help me.

[image: How it actually looks like]

Comment: I don’t understand your first problem; you are adding `inner sep=1ex` to the nested node while the other one just uses the default `.3333em`. The reason for the second problem is the nesting of TikZ pictures (which is just a bad idea).  For that to work, you need to add `remember picture` as an option to the outer TikZ picture (which the second will inherit) and then to compile twice. By the way, is there a reason why you use math-mode in lower node parts? Wouldn’t `\{no\_obj\}` just do?

Comment: Hey thanks for both advices, actually yes, there was a reason, because `\{no\_obj\}` were my first thought as well, but sth went wrong. Ive edited into it, so the remember picture option works fine. Is there a better way then nesting tikz pictures?

Answer (score 2):

Ive hacked it now via text width, but I think its not the way it should be done, plus, its ugly and I need to set it up for each picture manually.
This is what I got, I would love to see a better solution:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart} 

\begin{document}    


\tikzset{every loop/.style={min distance=1mm,in=110,out=70,looseness=2}}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->, thick, remember picture]
    \node (0) at (-2,1) {};

    \node[draw, shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, text width=5cm,
               text height = 3.5cm, text centered] (A) at (0,0) {
        \begin{tikzpicture}[->, thick]
            \node[draw, shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, text width=2cm, text height = 0.3cm, text centered] (test) {Sound \nodepart{two} 0 \{ \}};

            \node[draw, shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, text width=2cm, text height = 0.3cm, text centered] (Atest) at (0,2) {Test \nodepart{two} 0 \{ \}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \nodepart{two} 0 \{ \}}; %First Error

    \node[draw, shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2] (B) at (4,0) {Camera     \nodepart{two} 5 \{no\_obj\}};

    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
         (A) edge [loop above] node [above] {no\_obj} (A)
         (A.one east) edge node [above] {obj} (B.one west)

         (test.one east) edge node [below] {no\_obj, obj} (B.two west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]